# Is there a way to set the physical top/left desktop pixel position of the console app window itself?

Tags: .net, console-application

Some research has told me that the .NET console app API doesn't natively support setting the position of the console window itself at any X/Y location on your destop.  This is disheartening because I have two monitors, one being my primary code monitor and the other where I display my UI (ASP.NET web page, console app, WinForms window, etc).  When I execute my console app, it wants to open behind Visual Studio, but I want it to open on my other monitor.

Do I need to call the Win32 API in order to do this?  Is there another way?

**Update:** kingalligator's solution works perfectly when using arbitrary, hardcoded values in the `MoveWindow()` API call.  However, when applying RECT dimensions taken from the GetWindowRect() API call, you need to set the height by subtracting `.top` from `.bottom` as shown below.  If you just pass in `.bottom`, the window will incrementally increase height.  Oddly, you don't have to do this math with `.left` and `.right` which is what had me so confused.

```
RECT rect = new RECT();
IntPtr ptr = GetConsoleWindow();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    GetWindowRect(ptr, ref rect);
    MoveWindow(ptr, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom - rect.top, true);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it looks like there is a way - at least in C#, for that matter. You specified .NET, so I tried to do this in VB as well, but I could not make it work. The most important part of the following code is `MoveWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);`

The parameters are: handle, window x position, window y position, window width, window height, and a boolean value that represents whether you want the window to be repainted or not.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public struct RECT
{
    public int left;
    public int top;
    public int right;
    public int bottom;
}

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.Title = "Test";
            IntPtr handle = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, Console.Title);
            MoveWindow(handle, 100, 300, 200, 200, true);
            Console.WriteLine("Hi");

            RECT thisRect = new RECT();
            GetWindowRect(handle, ref thisRect);
            Console.WriteLine(thisRect.left);
            Console.WriteLine(thisRect.top);
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;

        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr zeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention =      CallingConvention.StdCall, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT rect);

    }
}
```

Comment: I tested this and it works on my dual monitor environment. When I changed the `x` value to `2600`, the console window appeared approximately in the middle of my second monitor (when Visual Studio was maximized on the other monitor).

Comment: +1. However, I would suggest using `GetConsoleWindow` rather than `FindWindow`. It's possible for multiple windows to have the same caption. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Jim Mischel: Thank you for pointing that out. I wish I would've came across that first; definitely a more sensible and straight-to-the-point function to use.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try it soon.  However, I should have mentioned in my question that I also want to get the current window position so that I can save it to a sort of state file so I can automatically set the position with the console runs again (I want it to remember the last position).  Do you have a quick solution for that?

Comment: I do, in fact. I edited my answer to include it. I've added a `struct` named `RECT`, a Win32 API function named `GetWindowRect`, a `Console.WriteLine` line which will display the window's left and top position. I tested this out and it works for me; I hope this gives you what you need.

Comment: @kingalligator See update to my question for an issue I am encountering here.  I've tried both `FindWindowByCaption` and `GetConsoleWindow` and both yield the same strange results.  Edit:  I figured it out!  Math indeed.  See update.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin: I'm glad that worked out for you. I didn't do any testing with GetWindowRect() beyond getting the positions, so thank you for figuring that out. That's strange how top and bottom function differently than left and right, though.